# Table designing and efficiency

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle12c

I am designing a database, in oracle 12c for my University assignment and have reached a point in my design, where I can't get much information about it.

**Scenario of my assignment**

You have been contracted by a UK internet service provider to completely overhaul their in-house software systems. This organisation provides broadband, fibre connections, telephone, IPTV and 4G connections plus several specific custom developments. The customer base is primarily students with the service being provided via their University. They are currently operating with a selection of legacy MySQL databases utilising the MyISAM database engine, as a result there are no suitable relationships in place.

**My question**

In the event of a RIPA request all the information stored about the student, including all the information gathered via tracking, should be accessible as a single query.

**[RIPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_of_Investigatory_Powers_Act_2000) request**

basically a RIPA request is when the policy wants to know everything that a certain individual has been up to, while using the internet, calls and etc.

how should i go about this? when designing my tables in the database, should i have a separate table where all this information gets gathered? example have a bunch of foreign keys inside the table to do with what the student has been up to?

**UPDATE**
the following is the rest of my assignment, just for a little more information about my question and for the curious.

The internet service provider requires the following for the users:

Students

•   Ability for students to register for and purchase products tailored by their University

•   Students to be able to view a notice board on an app, the website, the intranet and IPTV platforms.

•   The students should be billed for using recurring products.

•   Student activity should be tracked while using the internet and phone. Routers within the University will issue a configurable REST API query that provides the URL being accessed, along with details about the student and location. Phone calls are also tracked with phone numbers, duration and time of call also being provided via a configurable REST API query.

•   Phone calls require a suitable level of credit balance; the router to which the phone is connected will make an API request reducing the call credit balance throughout the call.

•   Students can make comments on notice board items and other students can comment upon those comments.

•   Vouchers are available to students to enable them to pay for items or to reduce the cost of the item, either by a fixed amount or a percentage of the cost. A record of the vouchers used should be maintained.

•   The television content watched should be recorded for advertising purposes. The IPTV system will request a configurable API that will provide the channel being watched, the student email and the time.

•   Students require a log in to access the notice board, broadband, telephone, IPTV and 4G connection; this is stored on the individual device after the first login.

•   Ability to access support via instant message, phone and email.

University Staff

•   The University should be able to add notice board items.

•   The University should be able to control products that are being offered to their students, limitations should be in place to ensure the University does not oversell connectivity available.

•   Notice board content can be targeted to specific layers, starting at particular Universities then halls of residence within the Universities and finally custom student groups (by course, by club, etc), these groups should be specified by the University.

•   University staff will require usage statistics.

•   University staff will need to utilise an admin area to make changes

Internet Service Provider Staff

•   The ISP should be able to manage the connectivity limitations

•   In the event of a RIPA request all the information stored about the student, including all the information gathered via tracking, should be accessible as a single query.

•   The ISP provides support via three methods, email, phone and instant messenger. The support emails and replies are managed on an existing server; this will issue a customisable REST API query that will provide the student email address, email subject, email body, date and time. Phone calls are manually recorded via desktop software, including details of the student who called and the nature of the query. Instant messages are recorded in the database and used to manage the instant message system.

•   It should be possible to create vouchers for student use; these vouchers should be limited by time, how many students use it and number of uses per student. The voucher should be accessible via a random code.

•   ISP management will require statistics about usage and sales.

•   ISP staff must approve new products before they are displayed to students

•   ISP staff should utilise desktop software to make any changes.

Including the following optional extensions will allow you to achieve a higher grading (see Grading Criteria- Implementation).

•   Room repairs – students are able to request repairs to their room. While they are logged in to the website they can specify an issue with their room. The room number should not need to be provided.

•   Free guest WIFI – guests are able to register to access the WIFI for free. Guests need to provide a home address, email address and phone number. The phone number must be confirmed before they can access the WIFI, this is managed with an existing server that sends a text message based on a REST API request and once it has been confirmed issues a REST API query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would start by creating a "pure" relational model, based on what you know. You can then see if you need to do anything clever to meet that specific RIPA query requirement.

The entities you have described are:

- the system has many **customers**
- a customer has one or more **services**
- a service has a *type* (broadband, TV, 4G, etc.)
- a service has 0 or more monitorable **events**
- an event has a *type*(make phone call, watch TV show, request URL etc.)
- an event has data; each event type has a different schema for that data

There are likely lots of other interesting things to model - billing data, etc. - but your scenario doesn't mention them, so I won't worry about them.

If the entities above are correct, your schema is pretty obvious:

```
Customer
-----------------
CustomerID (PK)
Name
...

Service
--------------
ServiceID (PK)
Name
Type
.....

CustomerService
--------------------------
CustomerID (FK)
ServiceID (FK)


Event
-------------------------
CustomerID (FK)
ServiceID (FK)
Type
Date
Event_Data
```

The remaining challenge is "how do we store event data"? As you haven't specified any requirements other than "list it", I'd suggest either a text field to store the raw data, or XML/JSON to allow smarter queries (e.g. "find all events where someone started to watch Homeland on IPTV") - but as you haven't specified this requirement, you may not need to do this.

Your RIPA query would be something like:

```
select customer.*, 
       service.*, 
       customer_service.*,
       event.*
from customer
inner join customer_service on customer.customerID = customer_service.customer_id
inner join service on customer_service.service_id = service_service_id
inner join event on customer.customer_id = event.customer_id
inner join event on service.service_id = event.service_id
where customer_id = ?
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, when you said that are likely lots of other interesting things to model - billing data, etc but I didn't feel right posting the complete assignment here. the visualisation in your answer made it very easy for me to find my feet and design this database and that query at the end was a great bonus.  i will be connecting via JSON to the front end, which i am yet to design.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a table to maintain users, another one to maintain services. Then another table to map user and services.

This will allow you to easily add/update/remove services. Removal can be done by marking service as inactive using a flag. This will allow retaining old data while new ones won't be using these services.

Update:
Your user table and services table will  not be linked to each other directly through keys. The reason is that you have many to many relationship between user and services. One user can have many services and each service can be used by many users.

Instead, UserServiceMap table will have both user and services id as foreign keys. While getting data, you can join three tables and get the result. The map table should have its own primary key instead of using composite key. This  will help users to stop and restart services.

Comment: i would be looking at one to one relationship between, users table and the table which will be mapping user + services and the same one to one relationship between services and the mapping table, is that what you are saying?